# Jquery Dynamically update select from input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need little help with this I tried updating select option with user input but it only shows empty option. Here's my code and a jsfiddle link

```js
$("#select").append($("<option></option>").val("Clothes").html("Clothes"));

$("#butt").click(function() {
  var bla = $('#category').val();
  var valll = $('#category').attr('value');
  $("#select").append($("<option></option>").val(valll).html(valll));
});
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Category" name="category_name" id="category" />
<button class="btn btn-primary" name="add_category" id="butt">Add</button>
<select id="select"></select>
```

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/Rhyno_xD/Lu3e9krz/2/)

Comment: Consider caching your selectors to avoid repeated querying of the DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('#category').attr('value')` will not return the current value. Please try this:

```
$("#butt").click(function() {
  var value = $('#category').val();
  $("#select").append($("<option></option>").val(value).text(value));
});
```

```js
$("#select").append($("<option></option>").val("Clothes").html("Clothes"));

$("#butt").click(function() {
  var value = $('#category').val();
  $("#select").append($("<option></option>").val(value).text(value));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="Category" name="category_name" id="category" />
<button class="btn btn-primary" name="add_category" id="butt">Add</button>
<select id="select"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lu3e9krz/3/)

**Javascript**

```
$("#select").append($("<option></option>").val("Clothes").html("Clothes"));

$("#butt").click(function(){
   var bla = $('#category').val();
   alert(bla);     
   $("#select").append($("<option></option>").prop("value",bla).html(bla));
});
```

**HTML**

```
  <input type="text" placeholder="Category" name="category_name" id="category"/>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" name="add_category" id="butt">Add</button>
  <select id="select"></select>
```